# Google Sheets script - "Cannot read property of undefined" (when it's not)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am trying to de-construct a [Google-Team's script](https://developers.google.com/adwords/scripts/docs/solutions/account-summary) for getting a report from AdWords and writing it into Google Sheets spreadsheet. I am testing it in Apps editor and getting the "Cannot read of undefined..." error.

I currently have two .gs files in my project:

**1. Function definition ("class"), `empty_row.gs` file:**

```
function SpreadsheetAccess(spreadsheetUrl, sheetName) {
this.spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(spreadsheetUrl);
this.sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);

this.findEmptyRow = function(minRow, column) {
    var values = this.sheet.getRange(minRow, column, this.sheet.getMaxRows(), 1).getValues();

    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        if(!values[i][0]) {
            return i + minRow;
        }
    }
    return -1;
    };

this.addRows = function(howMany){
    this.sheet.insertRowsAfter(this.sheet.getMaxRows(), howMany);
};

this.writeRows = function(){
    this.sheet.getRange(startRow, startColumn, rows.length, rows[0].length).setValue(rows);
};
}
```

**2. and a `main.gs`file where I instantiate the object:**

```
var spreadsheetUrl = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/someurl/edit#gid=1540200210';
var sheetName = 'baba';

function main() {
  var object = SpreadsheetAccess(spreadsheetUrl, sheetName);
  var emptyRow = object.findEmptyRow(1, 1);

  Logger.log("The empty row is: %s", emptyRow);  
}
```

When I run `main{}` I am getting this:

> TypeError: Cannot call method "findEmptyRow" of undefined. (line 6, file "main")

Why is my object undefined? I have defined:

- the spreadsheetUrl
- sheetName
- I have passed these to my function call
- and finally the function is defined in the same project, separate file

What gives? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>You shouldn't be trying to modify objects you do not own with the use of `this`. Especially in Google Apps Script. AFAIK `this` actually refers to the object that contains all the services code for Apps Script itself.</strike>

Create your own objects and pass those around instead of changing the object with global scope, while it will technically work to stuff everything into that object and reference it, it's discouraged.

I was incorrect in my reasoning. The problem I posted still stands though.

**The Problem:**

`object` is undefined because you are not returning a value from `SpreadsheetAccess()`. Nothing has been defined as nothing has been returned.

**Solution 1**

Here is your code with two changes. Newing up the SpreadsheetAccess function, and changing `spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);` to `this.spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);`

```
var spreadsheetUrl = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/someurl/edit#gid=1540200210';
var sheetName = 'baba';

function main() {
  var object = new SpreadsheetAccess(spreadsheetUrl, sheetName);
  var emptyRow = object.findEmptyRow(1, 1);

  Logger.log("The empty row is: %s", emptyRow);  
}

function SpreadsheetAccess(spreadsheetUrl, sheetName) {
  this.spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(spreadsheetUrl);
  this.sheet = this.spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);

  this.findEmptyRow = function(minRow, column) {
    var values = this.sheet.getRange(minRow, column, this.sheet.getMaxRows(), 1).getValues();

    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      if(!values[i][0]) {
        return i + minRow;
      }
    }
    return -1;
  };

  this.addRows = function(howMany){
    this.sheet.insertRowsAfter(this.sheet.getMaxRows(), howMany);
  };

  this.writeRows = function(){
    this.sheet.getRange(startRow, startColumn, rows.length, rows[0].length).setValue(rows);
  };
}
```

**Solution 2** 
Here is my modified code, this code works, I already tested it with my own spreadsheet:

```
var spreadsheetUrl = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/someurl/edit#gid=1540200210';
var sheetName = 'baba';

function main() {
  var myObject = SpreadsheetAccess(spreadsheetUrl, sheetName);
  var emptyRow = myObject.findEmptyRow(1, 1);

  Logger.log("The empty row is: %s", emptyRow);  
}

function SpreadsheetAccess(spreadsheetUrl, sheetName) {
  var myObject = {};

  myObject.spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(spreadsheetUrl);
  myObject.sheet = myObject.spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName); 

  myObject.findEmptyRow = function(minRow, column) {
    var values = myObject.sheet.getRange(minRow, column, myObject.sheet.getMaxRows(), 1).getValues();

    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      if(!values[i][0]) {
        return i + minRow;
      }
    }
    return -1;
  };

  myObject.addRows = function(howMany){
    myObject.sheet.insertRowsAfter(myObject.sheet.getMaxRows(), howMany);
  };

  myObject.writeRows = function(startRow, startColumn, rows){
    myObject.sheet.getRange(startRow, startColumn, rows.length, rows[0].length).setValue(rows);
  };
  return myObject;
}
```

Comment: I see what you did there :) - you modified the `function SpreadsheetAccess()` definition (the "class") so that a new object is created inside it (line: `var myObject ={};`), instead of in the `function main() {};` as I was trying to do. AFAIK, shouldn't the same result be attainable with `var myObject = new SpreadsheetAccess()`in the `function main() {};`? Meaning that my original mistake was the line: `var object = SpreadsheetAccess(spreadsheetUrl, sheetName);` which was supposed to be: `var object = **new** SpreadsheetAccess(spreadsheetUrl, sheetName)`

Comment: Ah! I see what you mean, I was incorrect in some of my reasoning since I've always treated Apps Script as a rather fragile creature. You can definitely new up instances of an object. I will correct my post to include that as well. You also have a syntax error in that you are calling spreadsheet instead of this.spreadsheet on line 3 of your first code snippet.

Comment: Completely understand it now! MANY thanks for taking the time to "teach me how to fish" instead of giving me the fish ;). One more thing: in `for () {}` inside of `function SpreadsheetAccess() {}` why do they return -1? Why not 0 or 1?